# Can you help me to find a formula to this experiment?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recursive-algorithms

So you have the following experiment:
[image: Experiment]

Could you find a function or sum for me to be able to calculate it for each step?

I have thought about something like this (b and a are the pipettes, x and y are the containers):
[image: b and a are the pipettes, x and y are the containers]

Im not a math guy so this is propably wrong but it would be nice if you helped me out.

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Comment: Pst, to...redeem myself, does solving the recursive equation count as part of your question?

Comment: Not sure if it will help me, but I´d appreciate it. Also, it doesn´t matter that you misinterpreted my qustion. Mistakes happen to everyone. The good intention is what counts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go together: For $x_0$ and $y_0$ which are initial values of $A$ and $B$, respectively. in first exchange we get
\begin{cases}
x_1=x_0+\dfrac{1}{10}y_0-\dfrac{1}{10}x_0=\dfrac{9}{10}x_0+\dfrac{1}{10}y_0,\\
y_1=y_0+\dfrac{1}{10}x_0-\dfrac{1}{10}y_0=\dfrac{9}{10}y_0+\dfrac{1}{10}x_0.
\end{cases}
next
\begin{cases}
x_2=\dfrac{9}{10}x_1+\dfrac{1}{10}y_1,\\
y_2=\dfrac{9}{10}y_1+\dfrac{1}{10}x_1.
\end{cases}
so we have following two sequences simultaneously:
\begin{cases}
x_{n+1}=\dfrac{9}{10}x_n+\dfrac{1}{10}y_n,\\
y_{n+1}=\dfrac{9}{10}y_n+\dfrac{1}{10}x_n.
\end{cases}

Comment: @Nico Check it for some steps.

Comment: I have a question. Can one rewrite the eqation to be able to input it into a calculator and get a solution for a specific n value or a graph?

Comment: I have not studied anything about this type of equations but maybe some software solve this type of equations or ask about _sequences simultaneously_ in **math.stackexchange** with sequences and series tag.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I´ll ask about that!

Answer (score 0):

We start with $1$ unit of water.  After one drop, we have $100-10=90\%$ water left:

$$t_1=0.9$$

And again:

$$t_2=0.9t_1=0.9^2$$

And again...

> $$t_n=0.9^n$$

Comment: No offense but It seems like you didin´t really read my Post. Check MyGlasses Answer, its right.

Comment: @Nico I'm sorry, but the above is what I interpreted to be the answer to what I thought was the question :-(